# Self join without same record appearing twice

Tags: sql

I need help in writing SQL and the context is,

-sample data is like below:

```
    a,b, count
    1,2, 10 
    4,5, 20 
    2,1, 5 
    5,4, 6
    6,7, 10
```

--Logic:

match for a row of a and b to its reversed row i.e b and a (where a=b and b=a) for example for 1,2 row the  2,1 rows is reversed and total count expected between them is 15

expected result set:

```
 1,2 15
 4,5,26
 6,7,10
```

or
      2,1,15
      4,5,26
      6,7,10

Any simple SQL to get above expected result would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code so we can help you tweak it. We arent going to solve this for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use self join:

```
mysql> create table test (a integer, b integer, count integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(1,2,10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(4,5,20);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(2,1,5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(5,4,6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT distinct a.a,  a.b,a.count + b.count from test a
          join test b on a.a = b.b where a.a< a.b;
+------+------+-------------------+
| a    | b    | a.count + b.count |
+------+------+-------------------+
|    1 |    2 |                15 |
|    4 |    5 |                26 |
+------+------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: when did people start downvoting valid answers?

Comment: Hi emaillenin, Thanks for the reply. but the expected result is only 2 rows but not 4 rows

Comment: Thanks again emaillenin, This solves to this specific dataset but a.a in not necessary to be less than a.b in actual data could be any numbers. only the matching criteria is a and b are reversed

Comment: no.. the reason I added a.a < a.b is that it will prevent the same record appearing twice during self join